# Not able to build an array & print it out in AWK

Tags: unix, awk, aix

I am hitting my head against the wall for something trivial, yet I don’t know why it is not allowing me to build an array by reading each row from a file before printing it back out on AIX 6.x.

```
Employee.txt
1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4|George|Bla|LA
5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago

bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0; next } { for (index=0; index<=FS; index++)  print index ":" employee[index] }' Employee.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0; next } { for (index=0; index<=FS; index++)  print index ":" employee[index] }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: error: invalid subscript expression
```

Got the same error using a different for loop.

```
bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0 } END { for (index in employee) { print employee[index] } }' Employee.txt

awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0 } END { for (index in employee) { print employee[index] } }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: error: invalid subscript expression
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `index<=FS` it should be some numeric value here so may be `index<=NF`

Comment: The desired output is to print Employee.txt out line by line. This appears to be a syntax error but I couldn't work out what it is. Thanks,

Comment: Got the same error after having changed index<=NF. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[NR]=$0 } END { for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print employee[i] }' file`

Comment: The following suggestion from anubhava worked.
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[NR]=$0 } END { for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print employee[i] }' file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is built-in GNU `AWK` function, thus you have syntax error when you try to use it as array key. Change `index` to `inx` to avoid syntax error and apply some changes to last action to get desired output

Let `file.txt` content be

```
1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4|George|Bla|LA
5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0; next } END{ for (inx=1; inx<=NR; inx++){print inx ":" employee[inx]} }' file.txt
```

output

```
1:1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2:2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3:3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4:4|George|Bla|LA
5:5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
6:6|Jody|Ford|Chicago
7:
```

Explanation: changed `index` to `inx`, change `for`'s check to less equal number of rows (`NR`), register last action as `END` (execute after processing all files). Note that [`for` for Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html) might be better fit for that rather than `for` you have used depending on your requirements.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: We no longer encounter the syntax error but it only prints out the value of inx followed by the colon symbol but not the Employee.txt record.
1:
2:
3:
4:
........
Thanks

Comment: RavinderSingh13's solution works fine for me. I get the same out output as he does, not the output George Jackson gets.

Comment: The following for loop still only print out the employee no. followed by a colon symbol:
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0; next } END { for (inx=1; inx <= NR; inx++) { print inx ":" employee[inx] } }' Employee.txt
1:
2:
3:

Comment: This for loop has worked:
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[NR]=$0 } END { for (i in employee) { print i ":" employee[i] } }' Employee.txt

Comment: FWIW `index` is usually abbreviated to `idx`, not `inx`. In 40 years of programming I don't think I've ever seen it abbreviated to `inx`.

Comment: Both for loops are now working. Apologies for the confusion earlier.
bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[NR]=$0 } END { for (i in employee) { print i ":" employee[i] } }' Employee.txt
4:4|George|Bla|LA
5:5|Wood|Atlanta
6:6|Jody|Ford|Chicago
1:1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2:2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3:3|Garry|Brown|Houston
bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { employee[$1]=$0; next } END { for (inx=1; inx <= NR; inx++) { print inx ":" employee[inx] } }' Employee.txt
1:1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2:2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3:3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4:4|George|Bla|LA
5:5|Wood|Atlanta
6:6|Jody|Ford|Chicago

Comment: I used `inx` as it is sometimes used in `python` when using `enumerate` for example https://downloads.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/documentation/API/cookbook_examples/docking_examples.html